# Is there a function in MATLAB that sorts a bidimensional array?

Tags: algorithms, matlab, sorting

**Is there a function in MATLAB that sorts a bidimensional array?**

This is how I would like to sort it:

The matrix:

$\left(\begin{array}{c c c}
9 & 4 & 7\\
1 & 5 & 2\\
3 & 6 & 8
\end{array}\right) $

will become:

$\left(\begin{array}{c c c}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6\\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}\right) $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible by vectorizing of the original matrix and subsequent reshaping

`>> A = [9 4 7; 1 5 2; 3 6 8 ]`

`>> reshape(sort(A(:)),size(A))'`

If you need to know original indices, function `sort` is able to return them. But it returns indices of vectorized matrix and therefore `ind2sub` has to be used

```
A = [9 4 7; 1 5 2; 3 6 8 ];
[t,indices]=sort(A(:));
[I,J] = ind2sub(size(A),indices);
row_orig = reshape(I,size(A))';
col_orig = reshape(J,size(A))';
sorted = reshape(t,size(A))';
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I think I will have to implement some algorithm manually because I need to know in another matrix or something, the original position of each sorted element :/ Is there a function or some trick that allows me to do this?

Comment: tHANK YOU VERY MUCH...I need to know the original position of each sorted element :/ Is there a function or some trick that allows me to do this

Comment: @nagaraj: I have converted your answer to a comment. Because you do not have 50 reputation points yet, [you can only comment on your own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757). So, you didn't do anything wrong; the "add comment" button will only appear for you once you gain 50 points. Here is an [explanation of reputation points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238).